# Django register users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication, django-users

I'm building a social media app and I want to create users without using the user creation form so I can build my own form. I am using. `User.objects.create_user()` however when I put `User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['un'])` I get this error 'UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username'. When I just pass a string it works fine however when I use the form data it doesn't.

Comment: Please share the code of your view and form.

Comment: The unique constraints fails, if you are trying to create a user with the same username as an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

`UNIQUE constraint` means in this context that the usernames of all your users must be unique. There cannot be 2 users with the same username. It seems to me that `request.POST['un']` contains a value that is already the username of another user.

**How to fix it?**

There might be several solutions to this problem, and you need to think about which one is applicable to your application.

**1. Make sure all usernames are unique**

This is the most obvious answer, but not always desired. For example, it might be the that you want to select users on email, and you do not care about the username. In this option the function `get_or_create()` might be very useful, which will select the user with the username, or, if it does not exist, create a new one: see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

**2. Make your own custom user model**

This allows you to customize django's build in User model. Therefore you can select users based on whatever you want (eg: email, google account, facebook account, or whatever is unique per user), and to not care about the username. The Django docs has a nice article about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model.